# Guardar respuesta en una variable de una petición http, para ser utilizada

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, get

se que la pregunta suena muy simple, pero la verdad es que no eh podido encontrar solución, les comento al momento de realizar una petición Ajax con Jquery, y guardar esa respuesta en una variable y luego querer utilizarla fuera de la petición `ajax`, la variable me queda como no definida, se que dentro de la petición puede utilizarse sin problema, pero me interesa poder utilizarla fuera del trozo de código de la petición.

Ejemplo:

```
var res;

    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function (xhrObj) {
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Authorization",
                "Authorization");
        },
        url: 'link',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (response) {
            res = response;
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });

    console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba colocando Async false.

```
var res;

$.ajax({
    async: false,
    beforeSend: function (xhrObj) {
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Authorization",
            "Authorization");
    },
    url: 'link',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (response) {
        res = response;
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});

console.log(res);
```

Editado:
Por defecto ajax se ejecuta de manera asíncrono, lo que quiere decir, que mientras realizas la petición puedes seguir ejecutando mas eventos y distintas peticiones, mientras que la petición del ajax ejecutado siga esperando una respuesta. Por lo tanto lo ocurrido en tu código cuando quieres mostrar la respuesta en consola, aun no existe. Al indicarle al ajax "async: false", ya deja ser asíncrono, por lo tanto se esperará a tener la respuesta del mismo para que sigas ejecutando mas eventos en la página.

Comment: Seria bueno que agregaras la información completa sobre usar `async:false` indicándole al usuario que esto hace que la interfaz de congele hasta tanto la petición sea resuelta.

Comment: Si bien esta es una solución válida, no es lo ideal, como dice @AlbertHidalgo trae algunas consecuencias no deseadas, por ejemplo que los eventos no funcionan mientras está haciendo el request.

Comment: Además está proximo a quedar deprecado https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-open()-method